# Lightning Data Service - empty error message

Tags: lightning-aura-components, create-records, force-recorddata

Today I'm struggling with something I really do not understand. I'm trying to make simple lightning component for creating new record of custom sObject. 
Problem appears on the save method. Result which it return is like:

> Problem saving record, error: [{"fieldErrors":{},"pageErrors":[]}]
>   TargetCreator.js:125
>  
>   Custom error:
>   {"state":"ERROR","recordId":null,"error":[{"fieldErrors":{},"pageErrors":[]}],"entityApiName":null,"action":{}}

Also force:recordData on initialization return me this:

> Record template initialized: undefined

And this is my code:

COMPONENT

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,lightning:actionOverride" access="global" controller="PickListController" >
    <aura:attribute name="NewTarget" type="Target__c" />
    <aura:attribute name="SimpleNewTarget" type="Object" />
    <aura:attribute name="recordError" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="objectsNamesValues" type="String[]" />
    <aura:attribute name="fieldsNamesValues" type="String[]" default="n/a"/>
    <aura:attribute name="dateFieldsValues" type="String[]" default="n/a"/>
    <force:recordData aura:id="TargetRecordCreator"
                      layoutType="FULL"
                      targetFields="{!v.SimpleNewTarget}"
                      targetRecord="{!v.NewTarget}"
                      targetError="{!v.recordError}"
                      fields="Id,Name,Description__c,Field_API_Name__c,is_Active__c,Object_API_Name__c,Date_Field_API_Name__c"/>

<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />



    <div aura:id="editDialog" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="header43" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
        <div class="slds-modal__container">
            <div class="slds-modal__header">
                <h2 class="slds-text-heading--medium">New Target</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around--medium slds-grid slds-wrap ">

                <lightning:input aura:id="targetName" name="targetName" label="Target Name" required="true" value="{!v.SimpleNewTarget.Name}" placeholder="Enter Target Name" class="slds-size--1-of-1 slds-p-horizontal_x-small"/>

            <lightning:input aura:id="Description__c" name="Description__c" label="Description" required="true" value="{!v.SimpleNewTarget.Description__c}" placeholder="Enter description" class="slds-size--1-of-1 slds-p-horizontal_x-small"/>

                <!--Object API Name Picklist-->
                <lightning:select aura:id="Object_API_Name__c" name="Object_API_Name__c" required="true" label="Object API Name" value="{!v.SimpleNewTarget.Object_API_Name__c}" onchange="{!c.getPicklists}" class="slds-size--1-of-2 slds-p-horizontal_x-small">
                    <!--Iteration -->
                    <aura:iteration items="{!v.objectsNamesValues}" var="item">
                        <option value="{!item}">{!item}</option>
                    </aura:iteration>
                </lightning:select>

                <!--Field API Name Picklist-->
                <lightning:select aura:id="Field_API_Name__c" name="Field_API_Name__c" required="true" label="Field API Name" value="{!v.SimpleNewTarget.Field_API_Name__c}" class="slds-size--1-of-2 slds-p-horizontal_x-small">
                    <!--Iteration -->
                    <aura:iteration items="{!v.fieldsNamesValues}" var="item">
                        <option value="{!item}">{!item}</option>
                    </aura:iteration>
                </lightning:select>

                <!--Date Field API Name Picklist-->
                <lightning:select aura:id="Date_Field_API_Name__c" name="Date_Field_API_Name__c" required="true" label="Date Field API Name" value="{!v.SimpleNewTarget.Date_Field_API_Name__c}" class="slds-size--1-of-2 slds-p-horizontal_x-small">
                    <!--Iteration -->
                    <aura:iteration items="{!v.dateFieldsValues}" var="item">
                        <option value="{!item}">{!item}</option>
                    </aura:iteration>
                </lightning:select>

                <lightning:select aura:id="Target_Type__c" name="Target_Type__c" value="{!v.SimpleNewTarget.Target_Type__c}" required="true" label="Target Type" class="slds-size--1-of-2 slds-p-horizontal_x-small">
                    <option>Select Target Type</option>
                    <option value="Count" >Count</option>
                    <option value="Sum">Sum</option>
                </lightning:select>


                <lightning:input aura:id="is_Active__c" type="toggle" checked="{!v.SimpleNewTarget.is_Active__c}" label="is Active?" name="is_Active__c" value="{!v.SimpleNewTarget.is_Active__c}" class="slds-size--1-of-2 slds-p-horizontal_x-small"/>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-modal__footer">
                <lightning:button variant="neutral" label="Cancel" onclick="{!c.cancelDialog}"/>
                <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Submit" onclick="{!c.saveRecord}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div aura:id="overlay" class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop--open"></div>

    <!-- Display Lightning Data Service errors, if any -->
    <aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.recordError))}">
        <div class="recordError">
            <ui:message title="Error" severity="error" closable="true">
                {!v.recordError}
            </ui:message>
        </div>
    </aura:if>
</aura:component>
```

---

CONTROLLER

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper){
      // Prepare a new record from template
      component.find("TargetRecordCreator").getNewRecord(
          "Target__c", // sObject type (entityAPIName)
          null,      // recordTypeId
          false,     // skip cache?
          $A.getCallback(function() {
              var rec = component.get("v.NewTarget");
              var error = component.get("v.recordError");
              if(error || (rec === null)) {
                  console.log("Error initializing record template: " + error);
              }
              else {
                  console.log("Record template initialized: " + rec.sobjectType);
              }
          })
      );


      var action = component.get("c.getPickListObjectsIntoList");

      action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
          var list = response.getReturnValue();
          component.set("v.objectsNamesValues", list);
      })
      $A.enqueueAction(action);

    },

    getPicklists : function(component, event, helper){
        helper.getFieldsNames(component, event);
        helper.getDatesFields(component, event);
    },

    cancelDialog : function(component, helper) {
        var homeEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToObjectHome");
        homeEvt.setParams({
            "scope": "Target__c"
        });
        homeEvt.fire();
    },

   saveRecord : function(component, event, helper) {
       var field_api_name = component.find("Field_API_Name__c").get("v.value");
       var description = component.find("Description__c").get("v.value");
       var object_api_name = component.find("Object_API_Name__c").get("v.value");
       var isActive = component.find("is_Active__c").get("v.value");
       var targetType = component.find("Target_Type__c").get("v.value");
       var name = component.find("targetName").get("v.value");
       var date_field_api_name = component.find("Date_Field_API_Name__c").get("v.value");

       console.log('field: ' + field_api_name);
       console.log('desc: ' + description);
       console.log('object: ' + object_api_name);
       console.log('isActive: ' + isActive);
       console.log('type: ' + targetType);
       console.log('targetName: ' + name);
       console.log('date: ' + date_field_api_name);

       var record = component.get("{!v.SimpleNewTarget}");
       console.log("NEW TARGET: " + JSON.stringify(record));
       console.log("TargetRecordCreator: " + JSON.stringify(component.find("TargetRecordCreator")));

       component.find("TargetRecordCreator").saveRecord(function(saveResult) {

           var resultsToast = $A.get("e.force:showToast");

                   if( ( field_api_name === null     || field_api_name === ""      || field_api_name === "Select Field API Name")   ||
                       (description === null         || description === "")                                                         ||
                       (object_api_name === null     || object_api_name === "")                                                     ||
                       (isActive === null            || isActive === "")                                                            ||
                       (targetType === null          || targetType === ""          || targetType === "Select Target Type")          ||
                       (name === null                || name === "" )                                                               ||
                       (date_field_api_name === null || date_field_api_name === "" || date_field_api_name === "Select Date Field API Name")) {
                       resultsToast.setParams({
                           "title": "Error",
                           "message": "Please fill all the required fields"
                       });
                       resultsToast.fire();
                       }else if(saveResult.state === "SUCCESS" || saveResult.state === "DRAFT") {
                        // record is saved successfully
                        resultsToast.setParams({
                           "title": "Saved",
                           "message": "The record was saved."
                       });
                       resultsToast.fire();
                       var recId = saveResult.recordId;
                       var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
                           navEvt.setParams({
                             "recordId": recId,
                             "slideDevName": "related"
                           });
                           navEvt.fire();
                       } 
                        else if (saveResult.state === "INCOMPLETE") {
                           // handle the incomplete state
                           resultsToast.setParams({
                              "title": "Incomplete",
                              "message": "User is offline, device doesn't support drafts."
                          });
                          resultsToast.fire();

                       } else if (saveResult.state === "ERROR") {
                           // handle the incomplete state
                          resultsToast.setParams({
                             "title": "Error",
                             "message": "Problem saving record."
                         });
                         resultsToast.fire();

                           // handle the error state
                         console.log('Problem saving record, error: ' + JSON.stringify(saveResult.error));
                         console.log('Custom error: ' + JSON.stringify(saveResult));                                         
                       } else {
                           console.log('Unknown problem, state: ' + saveResult.state +
                                       ', error: ' + JSON.stringify(saveResult.error));
                       }                       
                   });
   }
})
```

---

HELPER

```
({
    getFieldsNames : function (component, event){
        var action = component.get("c.getPickListFieldsIntoList");
        action.setParams({ ObjectApiName: component.find('Object_API_Name__c').get("v.value")});
              action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
                  var list = response.getReturnValue();
                  component.set("v.fieldsNamesValues", list);
              })
              $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },

    getDatesFields : function (component, event){
            var action = component.get("c.getPickListDatesIntoList");
            action.setParams({ ObjectApiName: component.find('Object_API_Name__c').get("v.value")});
                  action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
                      var list = response.getReturnValue();
                      component.set("v.dateFieldsValues", list);
                  })
                  $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

Comment: Question, is the `Target__c` object has a master detail relationship to another object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. Somewhere during the merge with master branch, system-administrator profile somehow changed two fields of Target__c to be not editable. Code is 100% fine. Just another problem with Salesforce debugging...

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the solution provided, check the field level security for all fields. There may even be fields you didn't intentionally set that are part of the object, I used something like this just before the .saverecord operation:

alert(JSON.stringify(component.get("v.contactRecord)))

(where contact record is the object to be saved) to view the JSON of the object to see all the fields it's trying to save.